Issue with Default Email Preference Settings During Salesforce User Creation
We're experiencing an issue during data migration in Salesforce. When creating new users, the fields EmailPreferenceAutoBCC and EmailPreferencesStayInTouchReminder are automatically set to true, even though we set them to false. This doesn't occur during updates; they work fine. We've tested in multiple independent orgs with the same result.
Has anyone else encountered this or know of an official document explaining it? Also, is there a setting to control these fields for all new users in bulk rather than individually?
Thanks!

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.
